# Limit with missing variables

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find the values for $a$ and $b$ such that 
>   $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{a + bx} - \sqrt{3}}{x} = 3$$

Basically what I did so far was I started by multiplying by the conjugate. and obtained $$\frac{a+bx-3}{x(\sqrt{a+bx}+\sqrt 3)}$$ I don't know what to do after this.

Comment: You might find this [guide to MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) helpful. Please verify that the post still says what you intended.

Comment: yes its exactly what I wanted to say

Comment: You know that $a=3$, otherwise the limit cannot be finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: The denominator tends to zero as $x$ does, so the numerator also has to go to zero. Setting $x = 0$ in the numerator shows that $a$ is necessarily $3$. Now simplify, cancel an $x$ in the fraction, and find $b$.

Comment: So I substituted a for 3 and simplified and got (b/√(3+bx)+√3x)=3

Comment: @Donutmunch Yes. Now take $x = 0$.

Comment: so the answer is b=3√3?

Answer (score 2):

$$ \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{a+bx}-\sqrt{3}}{x}=3 \Longrightarrow  \lim_{x \to 0}x\cdot\frac{\sqrt{a+bx}-\sqrt{3}}{x}=0 \cdot3=0$$

$$ i.e. \quad\lim_{x \to 0} (\sqrt{a+bx}-\sqrt{3})=0 \quad \therefore \sqrt{a}=\sqrt{3} ,\quad a=3$$

then

$$ \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{3+bx}-\sqrt{3}}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(3+bx)-3}{x(\sqrt{3+bx}+\sqrt{3})}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{b}{(\sqrt{3+bx}+\sqrt{3})}=3 $$

We can find that

$$ \frac{b}{2\sqrt{3}}=3 , \quad b=2\sqrt{3}. $$

This is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Being finite, numerator $\to 0\,\Rightarrow\,a = 3,$ so it is $\,\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}x = f'(0),\ \ \ f(x) = \sqrt{3+bx}$